# Completely uninstall confluent on linux

Tags: apache-kafka, apt, confluent-platform

I want to completely uninstall confluent. I installed it following the instructions on their site. There were three simple steps:

```
$ wget -qO - https://packages.confluent.io/deb/4.0/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/4.0 stable main"

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

Now how can I remove/uninstall it. I cant find anything related to it.

Comment: I had an issue where I wanted to start over again. Confluent have the configuration stored in /tmp and the file /tmp/confluent.current points to the directory. Delete this directory and remove the packages. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all installed packages from `confluent`.

```sh
sudo apt-get remove 'confluent*'
```

Note that you have to use `apt-get`, `apt` won't work. You can use the option `--dry-run` to see what would be deleted without performing it.

Comment: centos `yum remove confluent*`

Answer (score 0):

Should be the same as any other apt package

```
sudo apt-get remove confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

This should clean up packages and configuration files, not any external directories of Kafka, Zookeeper, or other services you've configured

Comment: is it the perfect way to clean up confluent Kafka-connect as well ?

Comment: This should remove everything, including Connect

Comment: It's not cleaning up systemctl ones

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to purge confluent from Ubuntu, run the following cmds.:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'confluent.'
sudo apt-get remove 'kafka.'
sudo apt autoremove
```

Exclude 'zookeeper.', since Apache ZooKeeper is a standalone server and might have other applications within Ubuntu.

Then delete the confluent installation directory. Following this any confluent CLI cmd. should prompt `confluent: command not found`.